# organization browser inside my site in sharepoint not working

Tags: organization-browser

organization browser inside my site in sharepoint not working and it displays "WebPage Not Found" what may be the reason?

Comment: I have the same issue. Organization Browser link in Mysite redirects to "Web page cannot be found".
Can anyone help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Even i have the same issue. .. :(

Answer (score 1):

Has this already functioned?

If not, you'll need to verify that  **User Profile Synchronization** service is active in Central Administration. Once its started go to **your service applications** and select **User Profile Service** application and click **Manage** on the ribbon. Once you do that under the profile synchronization connections create a new connection. Wait until the profile synchronization is over and then go to the organization browser and you will see the the results.

For screenshots alongside the steps, visit the following site: http://sampathlive.wordpress.com/2010/03/03/organization-browser-in-sharepoint-2010/

Comment: It was functioning before . But Now Its Not Working. Please Give Me Solution.Otherwise if Organization Browser not functioning means what may be cause?

Answer (score 1):

It got fixed!!! :)

First thing you need to check when u get "Webpage cannot be found" issue is:
1.  check Organizationview.aspx page is renamed or removed , you can check this by opening mysite using sharepoint designer.

Hope this will help you.